# How Smooks handle array of bytes

Tags: byte, freemarker, smooks

I have a class Vo that contains a member of type byte[] . now I want to write the whole object data of this class to a file and I use smooks API with below configuration :

smookConfig.xml:

```
<ftl:template><!--<#list objectVo.arrayOfBytes as oneByte> ${oneByte}</#list>--> </ftl:template>
```

now after creating object and populate all the data and after exporting it to a file using smooks API, when I open the file in binary reader I can see that the bytes are converted into their ASCI code so if the byte was 0x00 in VO then when I open the file I will find it as 0x30 which is the ASCI code of charcter 0 . 
I wonder if there is any way in smooks to export that data of bytes without any conversion so that it will do the same as java OutputStream.write(byte[]) which print the binary data without any conversion .

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, FreeMarker is a *text* template engine. Its output goes into a `Writer`, not directly into an `OutputStream`. Surely if you know what the output charset is, and it's not UTF-something or other multi-byte charset, then you can cheat... and for the cheating you will have to write a custom directive (`TemplateDirectiveModel`) or just call a Java method that returns a `String` like that (I don't know if Smooks lets you expose some plain Java objects).

Comment: Thank you ddekany for your response. Actually the data bytes I am trying to output belong to jpg image data bytes. and the receiver of data want it in Binary and does not want it even in Base64 . so I guess smooks API is no use for me in this case . thank you .